# WordPress site isn’t reachable after site & home URL modification

Tags: site-url, home-url, dns

First of all the technical details:

- OrangePi Zero (512Mb)
- Debian for Orange Pi
- Apache2
- PHP5
- MYSQL
- Wordpress

I have at home an OrangePi and I installed a WordPress on it. I registered a DNS name (`exlample.ddns.net`) on `noip.com`.

I used [the following guide](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) to the installation:

After the installation, the blog site is at home reachable and manageable, but from outside can't reachable (It try reach my private address): So I modified the site & home URL in WordPress settings. After that I can reach the site from outside with the DNS name properly, but I cannot reach the blog site from home (only from outside).

Do you have any idea on this issue?

Comment: What hostname did you set up in apache? What was the settings in site & homeurl, and what did you change it to?

Comment: the site and home url were: http://private ip

Comment: now: http://example.ddns.net
in apache I didn't modified any settings.

Comment: How about adding example.ddns.net to your hosts file with the private IP?

Comment: It's done, but the situation is constant :/

Comment: You did restart your browser after changing the hosts file, right? Look at the browser's dev tools network tab what IP the browser is connecting to, and what hostname it asks for.

Comment: I restarted the browser after the modification, but nothing happened. I checked the dev tools in the browser and the result is the following:
(I tried with the dns name)
Name: example.ddns.net
Domain: example.ddns.net

Comment: and at status: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: remote ip line is empty.

Comment: yesterday I istalled the system again:

Until wordpress installation works the normal index.php file from my private network and from the outside (from internet) properly, so the apache and the php work fine. The problem need to be with the wordpress.

When I installed the wordpress (see Page on the mentoined Website >>> WordPress Configuration), than I can reach my wordpress site only from my private lan and from the outside can reach the website without CSS.

Comment: But when I modify the site and home url in the dashboard of the wordpress from the private ip-address of the webserver to my dns name (from NOIP.com), than the mentioned situation will be reverse:
(I can reach my wordpress site from the outside with CSS properly but from my private lan the worpdress loads only without CSS.)

PS: I used only the mentoined link for installation:

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/3

Do you have any idea for this issue with this description?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. I added the DNS name and the IP-Address of the Server to the host file of my PC. So I can reach my website from the outside and from my private LAN also.